# Can I just substitute fresh ube for the "frozen ube, thawed" my recipe asks for?

Tags: substitutions

I got a recipe that asks for "frozen ube, thawed", and looking around my local stores and a quick google shopping search has failed to bring up any frozen ube, but I have found I can order fresh ube. Seeing some of the similar questions about fresh vs. frozen has me worried that it might not work or that I might have to do something besides sticking it in freezer and later taking it out.

*Other details that I guess might be helpful:*
The recipe is for bread for an extra blue blueberry jam sandwich with extra batter being used for blueberry muffins (will consider doubling each ingredient to ensure extra batter). The frozen ube is apparently counted as one of the wet ingredients to be mixed with the other wet ingredients before being combined with the dry ingredients.

**EDIT**: Oh, and the recipe calls for 16 ounces of the "frozen ube, thatwed".

Comment: Not 100% sure, so not posting as an answer. I would expect that frozen ube (purple yam) would be cooked by boiling or baking before freezing.

Comment: I suspect that by using the fresh ingredient you don't need to freeze it beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frozen ube is usually grated, raw, and packed in liquid. It comes as a solid block of ice.
Frozen ube is easily found in Asian grocery stores. Especially those that carry Philippine products. In my experience it is much easier to find frozen ube than raw. I expect that is why your recipe calls for it.

I haven't personally used fresh ube but from what I've read, grating it will give you all of the color and more flavor than frozen. Grating it would be messy but would also produce quite a bit of liquid that your recipe would require. I fear that shipping fresh ube you would receive a dryer than average specimen in which case you would have to adjust the liquid of your recipe.

Another alternative is ube flavoring. It ships easily and a tiny bit will stain your muffins ridiculously purple.

Comment: I might go with that alternative, especially as the search results for flavoring extract seem to be more affordable. Any idea what kind of ratio I should use when substituting it?

Comment: @MarkerMage - I wouldn't recommend substituting the extract directly, you'd be missing, what, 16oz of volume in your recipe (the liquids and solids both), that will be really tricky to balance.  You would probably be better off searching for an extract-using recipe to begin with.  If you must substitute it, I'd suggest finding a texture-substitute for your 16oz before worrying about how much extract to flavor with, since whatever flavors are in that substitute will effect how much flavoring you'd need to cover it.

Comment: @MarkerMage- I agree with Megha. Sounds like your recipe is using the ube for its color but it is also adding a lot of fiber and liquid that will need to be replaced.